# FormComponent.html:8 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'userName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I am working on a angular 7 and following the form.component.html code :

> {{ userForm.value | json }}
>
> ---
>
> {{ userModel | json }}
>
> ```
>     <div class="form-group">
>         <label>Name</label>
>         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" [(ngModel)]="userModel.userName">
>     </div>
>
>     <div class="form-group">
>             <label>Email</label>
>             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" [(ngModel)]="userModel.email">
>     </div>
>
>
>     <div class="form-group">
>             <label>Mobile number</label>
>             <input type="number" class="form-control" name="number" [(ngModel)]="userModel.number">
>     </div>
>
>
>     <div class="form-group">
>                 <label>Address</label>
>                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" [(ngModel)]="userModel.address">
>     </div>
>
>     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit Order</button>
> ```

user.js code

```
export class User {
    constructor(
        public userName: string,
        public email: string,
        public number: string,
        public address: string
    ){}
}
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './User';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title=['Angular','Vue','React'];

  userModel = new User('ash','ash@gmail.com','01233','asasas');
}
```

When i compile i get the error "userName" undefined.

Comment: Did you get `userForm is undefined` or `userName undefined`

Comment: I have just copied your code and run in the stackblitz. It is perfectly fine. See in the                                                                       
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p6cidm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @dileepkumarjami userName undefined

Comment: Yes thats right your code is right.I think importing user is something missed

Comment: as your code perfectly works in the stackblitz. I have also faced this problem. I just re-run the program. I am not sure whether it works on not but re-run project.

Comment: @Sabbir I didn't get you,Would you mind explaining to me ?

Comment: @ash15 Absolutely not, the core thing is you have a problem and you get the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <input formControlName="userName" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
```

Use this in every input field and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Change your User class like below

```
export class User {
        public userName: string;
        public email: string;
        public number: string;
        public address: string;
    constructor(userName, email, number, address){
        this.userName = userName;
        this.email = email;
        this.number = number;
        this.address = address;
     }
}
```

have a look here for more about [typescript classes.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)

as @Hameed Syed  said cross check once again for your class import statement.

**UPDATED**

your code seems fine for me, any how try to use Life Cycle methods from Angular for data binding.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './User';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title=['Angular','Vue','React'];

  userModel: User;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.userModel = new User('ash','ash@gmail.com','01233','asasas');
  }
}
```

Comment: explain something and downvote would make me clear about your thoughts ..

Comment: I changed but the error is appearing in the console.' FormComponent.html:8 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'userName' of undefined                                                                                                       I don't know why